# Why does brackets syntax language keep changing JSX to JS?

Tags: adobe-brackets

Although the files are .I set the default syntax for the file to .JSX for the .JS files I had. Yet, every time I close and reopen the folder, the .jsx file syntax reverts to .js syntax (for the .js files) and the default syntax is once again js. Is there any way to fix this? would I need to add a .brackets.json file, if so what would it even say?